# sticky session is not working on android browser

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-elb, sticky-session

I have an ingress alb with session stickiness enabled on target group!

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: stickiness.enabled=true,stickiness.type=app_cookie,stickiness.app_cookie.cookie_name=SESSION_ID,stickiness.app_cookie.duration_seconds=1200
sp
```

Stickiness works well in pc web browser but not in mobile app!

- Cookies created in pc chrome browser: SESSION_ID is set correctly, AWSALBAPP-0 is set correctly and the other ALB cookies such as AWSALBAPP-1, AWSALBAPP-2, AWSALBAPP-3 are set as `_remove_`"!
- Cookies created in Android device chrome browser: SESSION_ID is set correctly, all ALB cookies such as AWSALBAPP-0, AWSALBAPP-1, AWSALBAPP-2, AWSALBAPP-3 are set as `_remove_`!

Why all AWSALBAPP cookies are set as `_remove_` in mobile browser?

I have checked the cloudfront cache policy and origin policy and I think there is no problem in that.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I found that it happens randomly!
On first request response I could see that set-cookie header of `AWSALBAPP-0` with right value is set correctly. But in the next sub-requests `AWSALBAPP-0` is set as `_remove_`. That I guess it must be due to web-view multiple `set-cookie` header bug.